# JMSSerializer how to change handler for specific type one time

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I'm using jmsserializerbundle with the following:

```
jms_serializer:
    enable_short_alias:   true
    handlers:
        datetime:
            default_format:       'Y-m-d\TH:i:sO'
            default_timezone:     America/Bogota
            cdata:                true
```

now when serializer found a DateTime class converts to '2014-11-11T15:10:22-0500' format, the whole application works with that. but i need **in only one point use the 'Y-m-d' format** ¿how i can achieve it?

Comment: Looking for the answer to this also.  I am trying to migrate my app to ISO8601 timestamps and want to do this one entity at a time.  My default_format is 'Y-m-d H:i:s' and want to slowly migrate to 'Y-m-dTH:i:sZZZZZ'.

Comment: @shapeshifter check to [this](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle/issues/425) issue maybe can help us

Comment: Cool thanks rkmax will keep an eye on it. For now I'm just converting to a string in the entity.  Its not a persisted entity just a response object so the hack is isolated.

Answer (score 0):

On your one time entry, you could do the following

```
/**
 * @Type("DateTime<'Y-m-d'>")
 */
private $updatedAt;
```

http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#type